# Write a bashscript to double every newline character in a text file?

Tags: bash, text-editing

I need a bash script that will take a file and add a second \n character for every \n character already in the file:

that is:

> abcd\nbcda

becomes

> abcd\n\nbcda

how do I start.  OR, should I write it in another language and wrap it in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed 'G' file > newfile
```

or

```
perl -nae 'print "$_\n";' file > newfile
```

or

```
while read ln
do
   echo $ln; echo;
done < file > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

A very very simple way to do it.

```
cat inputfile.txt | while read a
do
echo $a >> outputfile.txt
echo "" >> outputfile.txt
done
```

Comment: wouldn't that be `echo '\n' >>outputfile.txt` or does echo automatically put in a newline?

Comment: @mechko - Yes, echo automatically puts in a newline

Comment: use `echo -n` if you *don't* want echo to automatically output a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can do this quite easily

```
sed 'G' file
```